# C#: How to get all Resources in Resources folder and their names

Tags: c#

I have added many images in my Resources folder to use them in my project. I want to call them dynamically in picture box by referring their names. My problem is:

1. How do I store images from Resources folder to a List or array?
2. How am I supposed to get names of all the images in a list or array?
3. How do I get names of images with a particular prefix like img1, img2.... ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the list of resources using `Resources` class of your project.

```
var set = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

// How do I store images from Resources folder to a List or array?
var resourceList = set.Cast<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>().Select(item => item.Value);    

// How am I supposed to get names of all the images in a list or array?
var nameList = set.Cast<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>().Select(item => item.Key);    

// How do I get names of images with a particular prefix like img1, img2.... ?
var dicResources = set.Cast<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
```